# page loading over and over

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am trying to ensure a navigation bar/parent page has loaded at the top of the page which wasn't happening initially.  My code below loads the correct navigation bar/parent page, however it causes the whole page to continuously refresh/load.

Entry is a query string coming off another app/service

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
        Dim newOption = cSession.User.p_Option

        If newOption = Option.Opt1 Then
            Session("lastUrl") = path
            Me.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                        Me.GetType,
                        "RedirectScript",
                        String.Format("window.top.location = '{0}'; ", ResolveUrl("~/userHome/userHome.aspx")),
                        True
                    )
        End If
```

Comment: That's what you told the page to do with that RedirectScript` - redirect to `"~/userHome/userHome.aspx"`

Comment: how do i have it redirect only once?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to have some sort of nested page or framed layout, or want to make sure that some other site isn't wrapping your content. How about adding an `if` block to your redirect?

```
String.Format("if (window.top.location != '{0}') window.top.location = '{0}'; ", ResolveUrl("~/userHome/userHome.aspx"))
```